# Call javascript function from an external HTML file

Tags: javascript, html

I have made a function inside a separate file from my HTML, I want to call that function when my select value changes, which it does, but it says the function is not defined. From this error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: filterByClass is not defined at HTMLSelectElement.onchange (questions:149)`

This is my HTML where the call is made:

```
<select id="filter" onchange="filterByClass();">
    <option value="{}">{}</option>
</select>
```

The options don't matter.

And this is my javascript *in a separate file*:

```
function filterByClass() {
    const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
    var db = new sqlite3.Database("../sql/homework.db");
    var classId = [];

    db.all("SELECT * FROM class WHERE className = ?", [document.getElementById("filter").value], (err, row) => {
        row.foreach(function (row) {
        classId.push(row.id);
            var questionId = document.getElementsByClassName("question");
            if(row.id != document.getElementById(row.id)) {
                document.getElementById("filter").style.display = "none";
            }
        });
    });

    db.close();
}
```

I know my code might not be right but that is because I am still learning javascript.

Also, I used `browserify` to be able to use the require, and turned it into `bundle.js`.
And this is the head link to the `bundle.js`: `<script src="bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`.

This is the first time I have used javascript in a separate file by the way, since I usually just put the code in the head directly.

Comment: `require('sqlite3')` indicates that this is a server-side script that runs in a node environment. While both web-browser and node use JavaScript, they both run in completely different environments. The server-side code does not have access to client-side elements/function and the other way round.

Comment: @t.niese I know I said in the question I used browserify to solve that problem, it isn't that which is causing issues.

Comment: `sqlite3` does not run in the browser. Browserify would not change anything about that, even if you solve the problem that `filterByClass` is not found.

Comment: I haven't used browserify for a while, but it most certainly wraps your code into a function. Due to that  `function filterByClass() {` will not available in the global scope. and `onchange="filterByClass();"` will only work if `filterByClass` available in the global scope. You could write `window.filterByClass = filterByClass` after the `function filterByClass() {` and then this error message is most likely gone, but you should use `addEventListener` instead setting the event handler in HTML.

Comment: @t.niese make your last comment into an answer so I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used browserify for a while, but it most certainly wraps your code into a function.

Due to that `function filterByClass() {` will not available in the global scope and `onchange="filterByClass();"` will only work if `filterByClass`is available in the global scope.

You could write `window.filterByClass = filterByClass` after the function `filterByClass() {` and then this error message is most likely gone, but you should solve the problem in that way, but use `addEventListener` instead setting the event handler in HTML.

But while this would solve the error message, it would still not solve the problem that `sqlite3` won't run in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

What I assume is that, the browser would have encountered an error while parsing the `bundle.js` and aborted parsing it (Which is more likely as you require sqlite in client side). That's why you could not call the function defined in it from HTML file.

I suggest you to check the console, and resolve if there is any errors or warnings shown.

Answer (score -2):

```
<select id="filter" onchange="filterByClass">
    <option value="{}">{}</option>
</select>
```

Take out the parentheses on filterByClass. It is being called too early, if it valid to call.

Comment: That's not true, in case of setting event listeners using attributes in the HMTL code, the value assigned to `onchange` will be evaluated at the time the event happens. So `onchange="filterByClass();"` is correct in that case.